# PyQt4: Resizing QGraphicsItem to a fixed QRectF

Tags: resize, pyqt4, qgraphicsitem

Is there a way to resize a QGraphicsItem to a fixed size?
I know it can be done with scale(float, float), but that seems like a bad direction to go when wanting to resize the item with mouse event. Is there a way to change the boundingRect() so that the Item will then fit the new size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be too late.

But probably my code at Github [PGraphicsItem.py](https://github.com/chiefenne/PyAero/blob/master/src/PGraphicsItem.py) helps you.
I derived my own *GraphicsItem* class from *QtGui.QGraphicsItem*.
There I set the size/scale in the paint method which you need to override.

The scaling factors I get from [PGraphicsView.py](https://github.com/chiefenne/PyAero/blob/master/src/PGraphicsView.py) where I subclassed QtGui.QGraphicsView. It holds a method *wheelEvent* which calculates scaling factors from mouse wheel increments.

**EDIT:**
In the [PGraphicsView.py](https://github.com/chiefenne/PyAero/blob/master/src/PGraphicsView.py) its the method *adjustMarkerSize* that recalculates the items to a fixed pixel size.

I do not no if that fits exactly to the question.